# How to get the duration of call started from your app?

Tags: java, android

In my app, when someone clicks on a button, a phone call is started. 
Can i detect when the phone call is finished, so i will be able to measure the duration of this call?

Tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For call start, use a `BroadcastReceiver` for the Intent with action `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. For the call end you want to use a `BroadcastReceiver` for the Intent with action `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. The Intent you receive will have an extra, `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE`, with value `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` when the call ends. You can then setup your interval timer values and track the duration.

Comment: Tnx, if i get it right, the 2. broadcast receiver is enough for me, because i start a call after the button is clicked?